# Why my button in cell (TableView) doesn't work?

Tags: uitableview, uikit

I don't know why my button in cell doesn't work. Where can be the problem ? It doesn't printing something to console like it isn't tapped.

```
extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Reservations.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.reusableCellReservations, for: indexPath)
        as! ReservationCell
        cell.restaurantName.text = Reservations[indexPath.row].restaurantName
        cell.reseravationTime.text = Reservations[indexPath.row].time
        cell.reservationDate.text = Reservations[indexPath.row].date
        cell.reservationGuests.text = Reservations[indexPath.row].guests
        cell.reservationStatus.text = Reservations[indexPath.row].status
    
        cell.cancelReservation.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnCellTapped(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func btnCellTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       print("pressed")
    }
```

And this is reservation Cell code.

```
class ReservationCell: UITableViewCell {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var restaurantName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reseravationTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reservationDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reservationGuests: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reservationStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelReservation: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnCellTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `print("inside cell") in the `@IBAction` func in your cell class, does it print? Does the button **visually** show it's being tapped?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't know why. All references are normal.

Comment: Is that "No, it doesn't print"? or "No, it doesn't visually show (highlight)"? Both? Is there a transparent view covering the button? Did you make sure you added your labels and the button to the cell's **contentView** (not the cell itself)?

Comment: It is just visually highlighted, there is no print output. I just make IBOutlets of labels and button, not additional contentView.

Comment: OK - well then your first step is finding out why the `@IBAction` in your cell is not executing. Are you designing your cell as a Prototype in Storyboard? Or as a xib?

Comment: When I add another button still I can pressed it and highlight is but no reaction is there. No print. 

I design the cell as a XIB.

Comment: Try creating a new cell class and xib, with just a single button. Connect the touch up to an `@IBAction` and see if you can get it to `print("tapped")`

Answer (score 0):

Because your code looks fine, we have to start with debugging.

- Launch the app and go to the view controller in question
- Execute action in Xcode menu: Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy
- Select the button in question
- Select 'Object Inspector' in the Inspector Pane (to the right)
- Below 'shadow color' you should see the list of target-action information

Check if the list has correct 'target' and 'action' values.

Screenshot for View Debug Hierarchy tool

[image]